# CoreUI Sidebar modifications

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, sidebar, core-ui

The documentation says it can be done by changing SCSS files. I downloaded the zip of the repo, and changed `_variables.scss`, modified `$sidebar-width:` to `250px`, but then I have absolutely no idea what to do. How to generate the one CSS file that will include my change everywhere? I experimented with using NPM, but I could not figure it out. I don't even know what NPM is, properly, or any such technology, for that matter.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can import in App.scss file, which is used in App.js.
`import './style.scss'`
where style.scss has your required css.